# React native- How to display login screen only one time in react native?

Tags: reactjs, navigation, react-native, user-registration

I am creating a project where I have a Registration screen, which is used for user to Register into the Application. This Register screen should only be visible the first time, so the user can fill it and log in, but when user opens the application at the second time the application must navigate to Main page.

I don't understand how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using local storage to store the fact that the user is logged in, you can check whether the user exists in storage. If the user exists in storage, set a state that represents the initial route component (to direct them to a screen other than login). Otherwise have the starting component be the login component.

If you're using NavigatorIOS, you might do something like this in your index.ios.js file:

```
return(
<NavigatorIOS
    style={styles.navigatorContainer}
    initialRoute={{
      title: this.state.title,
      component: this.state.component,
    }}
 />
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store credentials, or a simple boolean flag indicating that user is logged in in an [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html)

Some services (like Firebase) do this internally in their SDKs

Then, at app startup, you read from AsyncStorage and decide which screen to display.

Answer (score 0):

On Login Button

```
onLogin=async()=>{
  //Your login logic
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn',true)
    }
```

on Splash Screen

```
componentDidMount=async()=>{
  let loginStatus=await AsyncStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn')
  this.props.navigation.navigate(loginStatus ? 'Home':'Login')
    }
```

this might help you

Answer (score 0):

You should use localStorage to check if app have credentials and redirect the app to login screen like this

```
  useEffect(() => {

      const _retrieveData = async () => {
         try {
           const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@key');
           if (value !== null) {

             // let's go 
           }else {
              props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')
           }
         } catch (error) {
           // Error retrieving data
         }
      };

         _retrieveData()

    },[])
```